# Will not boot from memory stick

Tags: command-line

When I try to boot up, I have to press <kbd>F9</kbd> and choose my memory stick. It then shows a blank screen as follows `boot:`. I don't know what to type!

Comment: What other OS do you have installed on your PC? Also, are you sure it is a bootable stick?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set permanent boot options in your BIOS. You can set your PC to always boot from USB first if there is one present.

In the case you give, are you sure that your USB stick properly has a bootable OS on it? You might have just copied the files to the stick instead of making it bootable (a common mistake).